# XCTAssert with String not Equatable

Tags: swift, xctest

Why this

```
var sb = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var wc = sb?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pref") as NSWindowController
XCTAssertEqual(wc.window?.title, "Preferences", "Preferences window must have title Preferences")
```

gives me `Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'` error while

```
 var sb = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 var wc = sb?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pref") as NSWindowController
 XCTAssert(window.window?.title == "Preferences", "Preferences window must have title Preferences")
```

does not?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely possible to create an `Equatable` `Optional<T>` because `T` may not itself be `Equatable` and cannot be constrained as such in the instance declaration.  So, the `==` operator for Optionals is overloaded like so

```
func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

but there is no corresponding instance of `Equatable` to go along with it.  The end result is that Optionals can be compared with `==`, but may not be provided to methods ranging over generic `Equatable` types like `XCTAssertEqual`.  Another great argument for a type system with real constraints...